# List of elements in JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have a question regarding list of elements in xml

I am trying to delete everything under  and also the  tags.

But when I debug my list of param I noticed my list looks like this :

```
text
element
text 
element
text
element
text 
element
```

But  I want only the elements in the list and not the text so I can more easily delete the correct element.
How to do this?

This is my code :

```
public void deleteParameter(int row, int index) {

        int objTypeIndex = index + 1;

        File xml = new File(XMLEditorService.getXMLEditorService().getFile());

        try {
            XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter();
            org.jdom2.Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(xml);
            Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.xxx.com");
            org.jdom2.Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
            org.jdom2.Element typeContent = rootNode.getChildren().get(
                    objTypeIndex);

            List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param", ns);

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                Element element = list.get(row);   //remove correct element
                element.removeContent();

                System.out.println("element removed: " + element.getName());
                xmlOut.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
                xmlOut.output(doc, new FileWriter(XMLEditorService
                        .getXMLEditorService().getFile()));

            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

The list i am refering to is this line : `List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param", ns);`

[image: debug]

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example with an XML document, the method call (`deleteParameter(1,2)` for example), the expected result and what you currently see?

Comment: ok done Ive update. Just dont see why it would be relevant for the questoin.

Comment: Sorry it seems I misunderstood the question. It is still unclear to me, but hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: ok the list of Elements contain : text, Element, text, Element etc. But I want only the element, element, element. Is there a way to filter away the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call: `element.removeContent();` does not remove the Element from its parent, but instead it removes all content from the element (makes it empty).

You probably just want to do: `element.detach();` instead.... which will remove the Element (and as a result all of its content too) from the document.

Comment: Ok maybe my question was unclear : The list of Elements contain : text, Element, text, Element etc. But I want only the element, element, element so I can delete the correct <param>. Is there a way to filter away the text?

Comment: @Sembrano I think you are wrong. The "List of Elements" will not contain "Text". The list of 'Content' will contian Text, but `typeContent.getChildren("param", ns)` will only contain `Element`s

Comment: aight its true its the contentList now when you are telling me, I stil dont understand this. I posted my list content from my debugging on a picture. And what is this "text" and why does it create it?

Comment: The text is the 'space' between the Elements that are in the source document when you read it from the file

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JDOM2 filter to get elements of a specific type.
Look at [This](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-filters.jsp) example to see how to retrieve specific elements of the XML using Filters in JDOM2.